# Proving that a relation is an equivalence relation by proving it is transitive

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

I came up with this question , which I have to prove that it is an equivalence relation

Define a function f : R → R by f(x) = x^2 + 1. For a, b ∈ R define a ≃ b to mean that f(a) = f(b)

I have done proving that it is a reflexive and also symmetric , I am bit stuck at the transitive part 
Thankyou so much.

Comment: Suppose $ a \sim b$ , and $ b \sim c$. Then, $ f(a) = f(b)$, and $ f(b) = f(c) \implies f(a) = f(c) $. Thus, $ a \sim c$ by definition.

Comment: thank you so much @P-addict

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f(a)=f(b)$ and $f(b)=f(c)$, then $f(a)=f(c)$. This works for *every* function, not just for that one.

Comment: Thankyou so much

Comment: oh I'm new , sorry , Thankyou again